# Looping through an xpath getting the right iteration each time in xslt 2

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0, saxon

I have a condition where I need to loop atleast once and so I have the following xsl code. However, this doesnt work as it always gets the last iterations value. How can I tweak this so it gets the right iteration on each loop?

```
 <xsl:variable name='count0'>
    <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test='count($_BoolCheck/BoolCheck[1]/CheckBoolType) = 0'>
      <xsl:value-of select="1"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select='count($_BoolCheck/BoolCheck[1]/CheckBoolType)'/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:for-each select="1 to $count0">
  <xsl:variable name='_LoopVar_2_0' select='$_BoolCheck/BoolCheck[1]/CheckBoolType[position()=$count0]'/>
  <e>
    <xsl:attribute name="n">ValueIsTrue</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="m">f</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="d">f</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:if test="(ctvf:isTrue($_LoopVar_2_0/CheckBoolType[1]))">
      <xsl:value-of select="&quot;Value True&quot;"/>
    </xsl:if>
  </e>
</xsl:for-each>
```

The xml file is as follows:

```
<BoolCheck>
<CheckBoolType>true</CheckBoolType>
<CheckBoolType>false</CheckBoolType>
<CheckBoolType>1</CheckBoolType>
<CheckBoolType>0</CheckBoolType>
<CheckBoolType>True</CheckBoolType>
<CheckBoolType>False</CheckBoolType>
<CheckBoolType>TRUE</CheckBoolType>
<CheckBoolType>FALSE</CheckBoolType>
</BoolCheck>
```

In this case I need to iterate through each iteration of CheckBoolType and produce a corresponding number of values. However, in the above example if there were no CheckBoolType iterations I would still like the iterations to enter the for-each loop atleast once. i hope that clarifies it a little more.

Comment: You might want to show us an XML input sample and the corresponding result you want to create, explaining the relationship between the two samples. Then you can also show a minimal but complete sample of the XSLT code together with the result you get.

Comment: I think I got the answer to this I just needed to declare a variable inside the for-each like :<xsl:variable name="c" select='number(.)'/>
        <xsl:variable name='_LoopVar_2_0' select='$_BoolCheck/BoolCheck[1]/CheckBoolType[position()=$c]'/>

Comment: The context item inside of the for-each with `1 to ...` is an integer so `<xsl:variable name="c" select='number(.)'/> <xsl:variable name='_LoopVar_2_0' select='$_BoolCheck/BoolCheck[1]/CheckBoolType[position()=$c]'/>` would simply be written as `<xsl:variable name='_LoopVar_2_0' select='$_BoolCheck/BoolCheck[1]/CheckBoolType[current()]'/>`. But `for-each` is not a loop and whether you need all those variables at all I am not sure, I have so far not understood what you want to achieve.

Comment: I think your `xsl:if` test is wrong. `$_LoopVar_2_0` is set to be a `CheckBoolType` node, so the expression is looking for a `CheckBoolType` that is a child of that. I think it should be `<xsl:if test="(ctvf:isTrue($_LoopVar_2_0))">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First observation: your declaration of $count0 can be replaced by

```
<xsl:variable name="temp" select="count($_BoolCheck/BoolCheck[1]/CheckBoolType)"/>
<xsl:variable name="count0" select="if ($temp=0) then 1 else $temp"/>
```

(Sorry if that seems irrelevant, but my first step in debugging code is always to simplify it. It makes the bugs much easier to find).

When you do this you can safely replace the predicate `[position()=$count0]` by `[$count0]`, because $count0 is now an integer rather than a document node. (Even better, declare it as an integer using `as='xs:integer'` on the `xsl:variable` declaration.)

But hang on, `$count0` is the number of elements being processed, so `CheckBoolType[$count]` will always select the last one. That's surely not what you want.

This brings us to another bug in your code. The value of the variable `$_LoopVar_2_0` is an element node named `CheckBoolType`. The expression `$_LoopVar_2_0/CheckBoolType[1]` is looking for children of this element that are also named `CheckBoolType`. There are no such children, so the expression selects an empty sequence, so the boolean test is always false.

At this stage I would like to show you some correct code to achieve your desired output. Unfortunately you haven't shown us the desired output. I can't reverse engineer the requirement from (a) your incorrect code, and (b) your prose description of the algorithm you are trying to implement.

Comment: I was merely trying to understand how to get the current iteration within the for-each loop, but you make some good points that revealed other bugs in the code.

Comment: I have another situation which is similar but Im not sure why that doesnt work. Within the for-each loop, I have a condition like  <xsl:when test="(concat('a', ctvf:trim($_LoopVar_2_0/../OutboundShipConfirmationHeader[1]/OrderType[1])) = concat('a', &quot;SO&quot;))"> and trim is defined as  <xsl:function name="ctvf:trim">
    <xsl:param name="arg"/>
    <xsl:sequence select="replace(replace($arg,'\s+$',''),'^\s+','')"/>
  </xsl:function>. I keep getting the sequence of more than one element is not allowed in replace but I dont know how its passing in multiple nodes?

Comment: I can't debug it from that, but the first thing to do is to form the habit of declaring your data types on xsl:variable and xsl:param. It will make type errors much easier to diagnose as the detection moves closer to the source of the error.